# AWS ECS & Docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://<MY-ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:2375/<PROJECT>

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ecs

I'm attempting to follow the guide here for Continuous Integration / Continuous Deployment:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSGettingStartedContinuousDeliveryPipeline/latest/GettingStarted/CICD_Jenkins_Pipeline.html

I've run through all the steps and everything is deployed, but I'm getting the following error when a build is triggered in Jenkins:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://<MY-ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:2375/hello-world. Is the docker daemon running?
```

The full build output is as follows:

```
Started by user <MY_NAME>
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hello-world
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/securityvoid/hello-world.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/securityvoid/hello-world.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/securityvoid/hello-world.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 67019adfedd56dd6504ebdaa6430097855c936db (refs/remotes/origin/master)
Commit message: "Update readme"
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 67019adfedd56dd6504ebdaa6430097855c936db
 > git rev-list 67019adfedd56dd6504ebdaa6430097855c936db # timeout=10
[hello-world] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins3002143992924688341.sh
Flag --email has been deprecated, will be removed in 1.14.
Login Succeeded
[hello-world] $ docker build -t hello-world:v_2 --pull=true /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hello-world
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://<MY-ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:2375/hello-world. Is the docker daemon running?
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Googling the error its stated you need to run the Docker service, but shouldn't that be running on ECS by default?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the issue. I had failed to read the directions and instead of entering my Docker Container Registry into the "registry" field of Jenkins, I entered it into the "Docker Host URI".

By setting the URL to:

```
https://<MY-ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello-world
```

This error went away.